# Trying to install macOS Sierra on a 2017 MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, install, dmg

Background of the issue: A 2017 MacBook Pro was reset by the seller. I tried installing the OS, but encountered errors during installation.
I am trying to install macOS Sierra through Recovery mode. Here are the steps I carried out on the MacBook Pro that has the issue.

1. I reformatted the disk, with a warning of data loss.
2. `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD`
3. I downloaded the macOS Sierra 10.12.6 `InstallOS.dmg` using the `curl` command.
4. I mounted the `InstallOS.dmg` with `hdiutil attach InstallOS.dmg`.
5. I tried to install the `Install macOS Sierra.app` from the `InstallOS.dmg` to `Macintosh HD` volume with the following command.

   ```
   installer -pkg /Volumes/Install\ macOS/InstallOS.pkg -target /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
   ```

The OS seemed to install, and it said it will restart. The restart process was going fine, until it stopped with a circle and a slant line inside it. Now the OS will not load. I am only able to boot to Recovery. Also when I select "Reinstall macOS" option, disks are not displayed.

Comment: What model of Mac is this? So the Mac boots to recovery successfully, or not? Does it not boot up normally? Can you install macOS directly from recovery mode?

Comment: This sounds like you’re over complicating things. Which Mac or computer is doing the download of the installer and preparing it?

Comment: This is MacBook Pro 2017.

Comment: I got passed that error, but now faced with a different issue. The system wont load OS. I had to reformat the disk, with a warning of data loss. After that I was able to follow the instruction stated in my original post. The OS seemed to install, and it said it will restart. The restart process was going fine, until it stopped with a circle and a slant line inside it.Now the OS will not load. I am only able to boot to Recovery. Also when I select Reinstall macOS option, disks are not displayed.

Comment: I carried out the steps above on the MacBook Pro that has the issue.

Comment: Use Disk First Aid in recovery to check that the internal disk is ok and formatted correctly.

Comment: Jide: After step 5, what did you enter to get the `Install macOS Sierra` application to install macOS Sierra to the `Macintosh HD` volume? Also, are you booting the from a Recovery volume on the internal drive, Internet Recovery, or something else?

Comment: What version of macOS was it running *before* you attempted to install Sierra (10.12)?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. The issue is resolved. I had to format the drives. First I formatted the Main drive, then i formatted the Macintosh HD drive.